# java: How to split a 2d array into two 2d arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a program to multiply matrices (2d arrays) as efficiently as possible, and for this i need to split my two arrays into two each and send them off to a second program to be multiplied. The issue I have is how to split a 2d array into two 2d arrays, at specific points (halfway). Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what have you done so far mr magic?

Comment: What does it mean to split a two-dimensional array "halfway"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lets say you have a 2d array of strings like so

```
String[][] array= new String[][]
{
    {"a","b","c"},
    {"d","e","f"},
    {"h","i","j"},
    {"k","l","m"}
};
```

Now you need a way to split these arrays at the half way point. Lets get the halfway point. Figure out how big the array is and then cut it in half. Note that you also must handle if the array is not an even length. Example, length of 3. If this is the case, we will use the `Math.floor()` function.

```
int arrayLength = array.length;
int halfWayPoint = Math.floor(arrayLength/2);
//we also need to know howmany elements are in the array
int numberOfElementsInArray = array[0].length;
```

Now we have all the info we need to create two 2d arrays from one. Now we must explicitly copy create and copy the data over.

```
//the length of the first array will be the half way point which we already have
String [][] newArrayA = new String[halfWayPoint][numberOfElementsInArray];
//this copies the data over
for(int i = 0; i < halfWayPoint; i++)
{
    newArrayA[i] = array[i];
}

//now create the other array
int newArrayBLength = array.length - halfWayPoint;
String[][] newArrayB = new String[newArrayBLength][numberOfElementsInArray];
/*
 * This copies the data over. Notice that the for loop starts a halfWayPoint.
 * This is because this is where we left of copying in the first array.
 */
for(int i = halfWayPoint; i < array.length; i++)
{
    newArrayB[i] = array[i];
}
```

And your done!

Now if you want to do it a little nicer, you could do it like this

```
int half = Math.floor(array/2);
int numberOfElementsInArray = array[0].length;
String [][] A = new String[half][numberOfElementsInArray];
String [][] B = new String[array.length - half][numberOfElementsInArray];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if(i < half)
    {
        A[i] = array[i];
    }
    else
    {
        B[i] = array[i];
    }

}
```

And lastly, if you dont want to do it explicitly, you can use the built in functions. `System.arraycopy()` is one example. Here is a link to its api [System.arraycopy()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29)

```
int half = Math.floor(array/2);
int numberOfElementsInArray = array[0].length;
String [][] A = new String[half][numberOfElementsInArray];
String [][] B = new String[array.length - half][numberOfElementsInArray];
System.arraycopy(array,0,A,0,half);
System.arraycopy(array,half,B,0,array.length - half);
```

Comment: The issue I have with this solution is that my compiler does not like assigning the 2d array parts to the normal array with this line:         newArrayA [i] = array[i];          Is there any solution to this?

Comment: I have this working perfectly for the first half of the array (both the top half and the left half) but it will not work with the second half. I just keep getting index out of bound Exceptions.

Comment: I made a slight change, try that. But which approach did you take. The first, second, or third one?

Comment: `code int[][] newArrayC = new int[length-half][ROW];

 

 for(int i = halfwayPoint; i < length; i++)

 {

  for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)

  {

   newArrayC[i][j] = array[i][j];

  }

 }`  This works if the array size is [ROW][ROW] but obviously the first half is all 0s but i get the index out of bound exception if i try anything else. Annoying. Thanks for your help so far though.

Comment: It is because you initialize the array to `new int[length-half][ROW]`, but in your for loop, you have `i` going from `0...length`. So `i` will be larger than the array's first index allow. It should be something like this `for(int i = 0; i < length - half; i++)`