# How to split a 2D Array to left and right arrays?

Tags: java, split, multidimensional-array, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java: How to split a 2d array into two 2d arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463781/java-how-to-split-a-2d-array-into-two-2d-arrays)

What is required is to split this array:

```
int[][] bitblock = {
    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0}};
```

This is an 8*8 array , I want to split it into left and right arrays and store them here:

```
int[][] leftblock = new int [bitblock.length][bitblock[0].length/2];
int[][] rightblock = new int [bitblock.length][bitblock[0].length/2];
```

I used the method Syste.arraycopy and I was able to split the bitblock to up and down arrays, I am kind of struggling to split it left and right:

```
System.arraycopy(bitblock, 0, leftblock, 0, leftblock.length);
System.arraycopy(bitblock, rightblock.length, rightblock, 0, rightblock.length)
```

Can someone please help ? Thanks

Comment: Hope this help:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463781/java-how-to-split-a-2d-array-into-two-2d-arrays

Comment: You cannot do it with just two `arraycopy`s, your data is not contiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick nicely:

        `int[][] bitblock = {{1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
            {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}};`

```
    int[][] leftblock = new int[bitblock.length][bitblock[0].length / 2];
    int[][] rightblock = new int[bitblock.length][bitblock[0].length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < bitblock.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bitblock[0].length / 2; j++) {
            leftblock[i][j] = bitblock[i][j];
        }

        for (int j = bitblock[0].length / 2; j < bitblock[0].length; j++) {
            rightblock[i][j - bitblock[0].length / 2] = bitblock[i][j];
        }
    }
```

You could also use System.arraycopy, as it makes the code more clear for future inspection.
As of performance, I don't think it matters as long as your array is that small.

Answer (score 1):

For an 8x8 array, the chances are that there is minimal performance benefit in using clever array copying methods.  I recommend that you simply code this using nested for loops.  The code will be simpler, and you will (would have) gotten the job done quicker.

Comment: yeah..I figured if i can do it using a shortcut. it would be better programming structure, but yeah I'll do it nested loops

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < bitblock.length ; i++) {
    System.arraycopy(bitblock[i], 0, leftblock[i], 0, leftblock[i].length);

    System.arraycopy(bitblock[i], bitblock[0].length/2, 
                                    rightblock[i], 0, leftblock[i].length);
}
```

I personally do not think nested loops would be better in this case - you might as well use the functionality of `System.arraycopy` as opposed to reinventing the wheel yourself. In my opinion, this is easier to manage / read than nested loops also.